# Bootstrap thumbnails list margins

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fluid grid of items (product thumbnails) that can be filtered with JS/jQuery. But I can't find the best way to set the CSS for making the left margin be ok after I apply the filters.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and the thumbnails has a standard margin. I've used the example found here: [Margin problems with thumbnails in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576483/margin-problems-with-thumbnails-in-bootstrap) with small modifications for making the margin be fine without JS filters applied.

CSS:

```
ul.thumbnails > li:nth-child(1), ul.thumbnails li.span3:nth-child(4n + 5) {
  margin-left : 0px;
}
```

My markup is something like:

```
<div class="row-fluid products">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

NOW - this works fine until I apply a filter with JS that hides some of the `<li>` items. (using CSS by adding `class="hide"` to each list items that shouldn't be seen (does `display:none`)). Then the remaining items gets wrong margins, if for example the first item gets hidden then the second has a remaining left-margin which it shouldn't.

I thought of adjusting CSS with JS after applying the filter but this code doesn't work for me:

```
$("li.product.span3").css({ 'margin-left': '2.5641%'});
$("li.product.span3:not(.hide):nth-child(1)").css({ 'margin-left': '0'});
$("li.product.span3:not(.hide):nth-child(4n+5)").css({ 'margin-left': '0'});
```

Also this wouldn't address the responsive settings for the margin as this differ from different screen widths. The ideal solution is CSS only of course. Suggestions please...

Comment: consider doing a fiddle. The expected behavior should work without doing any JS style adjustment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not apply margins to first items, bootstrap take care of this by itself.
when using thumbnails you should not use the row class.

try this :

```
<div class="products">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
    <li class="product span3"><!-- product image and info --></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

with no extra css

Comment: Great, your'e absolutely right! I had a parent wrapper div with the row-fluid class that made it hard to find! Now it works without extra js or css. GREAT!